# Cannot read or write to private Github remote settings repository in IntelliJ

Tags: github, intellij-idea, settings

I'm using a private Github repo to host my intellij settings so that I can share them between workstations easily. Today I installed the latest version of IntelliJ and when I tried to import my IDE settings a got the following error:
sy
"Failed to set upstream repository: https://github.com/username/intellij_settings: https://github.com/username/intellij_settings/info/refs?service=git-upload-package
Not Found"

I tried resetting IntelliJ passwords, I even generated a new token for it. Turns out, when I made the repository public, everything worked fine.

This of course is a temporary solution as these repositories are meant to be private since they contain system path information amongst others. This is not an issue with the latest version of IntelliJ because I've had it with version 2021.1.3 as well.
Searching YouTrack issues, nothing similar comes up even though multiple people have had issues with Github connections, the issues are usually with checking out a project which worked fine for me, only the Settings Repository feature fails.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you are prompted to enter username and password when you are trying to add Settings repository?

Comment: The `?git-upload-package` part is an attempt to tell GitHub to use some particular software module; perhaps GitHub have removed that particular module recently? (In any case this is definitely not a Git thing, it's a bad interaction between IntelliJ and GitHub.)

Comment: That is why I didn't add 'Git' as a tag.
@RuslanKuleshov I am prompted to provide a *token* which I have. I have also deleted the IntelliJ keepass file which saves all passwords multiple times and re-provided the token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the settings sync works differently now.

Try to generate a new access token with `repo` and `write:packages` selected in "Select scopes".

It worked for me.